# storing values of resultset into different table based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have a table 'new_table' in mysql, I want to store the result into two different tables based on a condition i.e if the percentage is above 70 then the result should be stored in **dominant** else should be stored in **others**
from below table the result based on condition(if percentage > 70) should store values 80 and 75 in **dominant**  table  and should store 20 , 40 , 60 in **others** table
kindly help.
thanks in advance.

```
sku_id  new_total  percentage
  1        8          20 
  2        12         40
  3        14         80
  4        10         75
  5        13         60
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use create as select command like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dominant AS (
    SELECT * FROM new_table
    WHERE percentage > 70)
```

And for the second table same logic:

```
CREATE TABLE others AS (
    SELECT * FROM new_table
    WHERE percentage < 70)
```

Comment: how do I merge these two queries into single one?